# How to Import ESRI Geodatabase format .gdb into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase, translation

I ran into a problem when loading a ESRI Geodatabase format .gdb into PostGIS. I have data 2.5GB GDB file.
I followed some tutorials on the internet, but it seems that doesn't work out.

1. I created a database "SampleNY"
2. I executed this from the console:

   ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=SampleNY user=postgres" NYPluto/Pluto.gdb

But nothing happens, I didn't got neither an error nor a successful operation. 
Did I miss any steps?

Comment: Are you limited to using ogr2ogr?  Or are you open to other solutions?  FME should be able to do this easily.

Comment: I am open to any solution that can solve this problem ? Can you provide more details about how to do that ?

Comment: Try downloading [FME](http://www.safe.com/).  Create a new workbench and add a Geodatabase Reader and a PostGIS writer.

Comment: You might also try using QGIS.

Comment: But it seems like FME is commercial solution

Comment: It is a commercial solution.  You didn't specify you were only looking for free solutions.  I think FME has a free trial period.

Comment: I found in other answers Spatial Data Manager. http://www.mapet.altervista.org  This is a free windows tool to load shapefile and file geodatabase in Postgis and other spatial db.

Comment: What do you mean by "Spatial Data Manager"

Comment: Did you get anywhere? I've just used my (updated) command, below, successfully to import 4.2 million polygons.

Comment: Fme is the best solution ;)

Answer (score 27):

Try adding appropriate `host` and `port` arguments. 
And BTW, when I import a large GDB file, I also add these flags:

`-overwrite` (erases any mess you may have already inserted) and

`-progress` (displays a dot or number for every 10,000 or 10% records added):

`--config PG_USE_COPY YES` (greatly improves speed)

So the command (which should be a one-liner but i formatted here for clarity) becomes

```
ogr2ogr 
    -f "PostgreSQL" 
    PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=SampleNY user=postgres" 
    NYPluto/Pluto.gdb 
    -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES
```

Use a URL in place of "localhost" if needed.

Answer (score 12):

If there are multiple features in the gdb and you want to specify the Postgres schema and table names then follow:

```
#First get the featurenames from the gdb:
ogrinfo geodbname.gdb

#then import a feature into a table:
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=hostname port=5432 dbname=dbname user=postgres"
geodbname.gdb -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -nln schemaname.tablename featurename -overwrite
```

Comment: most helpful answer imo.  You might add that if you know the geometry type, you can set that for `-nlt` instead of `PROMOTE_TO_MULTI` (i.e. `MULTILINESTRINGZM`, `POINT`, etc.).  Also, I have noticed that esri gdbs often contain multicurve geometries, which will fail when using `PROMOTE_TO_MULTI` with `geometry type (MultiCurve) does not match column type (MultiLineString)`.  If you set `-nlt MULTILINESTRING`, it works (also works with M and ZM)